# Append a space with jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

I'm trying to append a space using jQuery.  Neither of these samples work:

```
  $("#mySelector").append($(" "));
  $("#mySelector").append($("&nbsp;"));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

How about

```
$("#mySelector").append(" "); // or with & nbsp;
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case I did the following:

```
$('.colwid10a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':empty')) {
        $(this).append("&nbsp;");
    }
});
$('.colwid12').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('a').is(':empty')) {
        $(this).find('a').append("&nbsp;");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use '\xa0', it is a non break space character.

```
$("#mySelector").append('\xa0');
```

Answer (score -1):

And, create a JQuery Plugin function to reuse it whenever you need to put space. This way you will be consistent throughout.

```
if(!$.space) {
        $.space = function​(noOfSpaces) {
            var space = " ", returnValue = "";
            for(var index=0; index < noOfSpaces; index++) {
                returnValue += space;
            }
            return returnValue;
        }
    }

alert("Stack" + $.space(6) + "Overflow");
```

Comment: This is irrelevant to the OP's question, he did not ask how to create a space padded string.

Answer (score -4):

Untested (and probably a bit overkill):

```
$("").append($("<p> </p>").text());
```